# Conceal with the highlighting of matching begin/end latex environment

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, conceal, plugin-vimtex

I want to use vim conceal feature with the highlighting of matching begin/end latex environment (vimtex plugin). When I use the following code

```
syn match texStatement '\\begin{itemize}' contained conceal cchar=-
syn match texStatement '\\end{itemize}' contained conceal cchar=-
```

with `set conceallevel=2`, I get the `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` concealed into `-`. But when I hover on `\begin{itemize}` the matching `\end{itemize}` (concealed in `-`) does not get highlighted.

So I added the transparent argument

```
syn match texStatement `\\begin{itemize}` transparent contained conceal cchar=-
syn match texStatement `\\end{itemize}` transparent contained conceal cchar=-
```

Now I get the highlighting of matching parentheses but the `\\begin{itemize}` and `\\end{itemize}` are not completely concealed, instead they get concealed into `{itemize}`.
I don't know how to use the contained and contains arguments to get around this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!